# Is it possible to use new relic with php / ZF in development localy

Tags: php, zend-framework, newrelic

I am very new (and confused) to new relic. Is it possible to install new relic with php localy in development, before use it in production? The reson I ask is because a have an app in development that receives data feeds from a service continuously and want to profile it. The app is made with the Zend Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any reason why you wouldn't be able to run New Relic locally. You might want to consider some of the other options like XDebug which might give you a few more options in your dev environment.

Comment: Thanks I will try it. I choosed new relic to profile database calls also rather than just php (XDebug)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use New Relic on your dev machine. It'll report data back to New Relic as usual. You can have your dev instance appear as a separate application in the NR web UI by using a different `app_name` setting in `php.ini`. See the [New Relic PHP agent  docs](https://newrelic.com/docs/php/php-agent-phpini-settings) for more details. That'll keep the requests you make in dev from adding noise to your production app's data.

Comment: Thanks. I want to mention though that new relic does not work in windows yet. My current dev environment for this app is windows

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, there's no PHP agent for Windows yet.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, NewRelic does not currently support windows. You can try other solutions, like Correlsense, which support both windows and unix PHP

Comment: Why do you mention Windows? The OP didn't ask if NewRelic works with Windows. You don't answer the question...

Comment: Have to down vote this since you went offtopic with your answer and promoted your own website irrelevantly.